# selecting column with blank rows , without specific cell range

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have a file in which I want my macro to go find specific header and then select all the data in that specific column. This column has blank rows in between. For example I want to select product column(see screen shot).

The challenge here is that I can’t use rows.count code because the column might change time to time, and I can’t use any specific cell range to write my code.

I cant select whole column as well because I need to copy product from two different tabs and paste them in to one file.

Is there a way I can write code using active cell and select range from top to bottom?

```
Sheets("PB").Select
Cells.Find(What:="product").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Comment: are you trying to select just the data and exclude the blanks? or the whole column?

Comment: I want to select just the data as well as the blanks but selecting whole column wont  help as I need to add more line from other tab as well.

Comment: Lets take a step back. What do you intend to do after selecting the column? I ask because the `.Select` is just a middle operator for your actual intentions. Lets cut out the middle man and solve the actual ask

Comment: As far as determining the range to select, use a different column to find the last used row. It looks like your `Dept` column has no blanks. So you should use that as your last row indicator and apply that row to your `Product` column.

Comment: in VBA use xlUp on the Dept column, to get the number of rows you want to target.

Comment: Taking a second step back: How do you determine which column has to be copied? It's possible the macro can do it for you

Comment: @urdearboy - Yes, Selecting last row from department will help, Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

well, you could get the row number of the last row filled (no matter if it is changing, everytime you run the sub it will get the last row of the column).

```
lastRow = worksheets("PB").cells(rows.count,7).end(xlup).row
```

then you can set the range as:

```
set myRange = worksheets("PB").range("B1:B" & lastRow )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a good start and, as you've stated, you just need to select the number of rows in a reliable fashion.

So get the range we're going to mine for blanks:

```
Set rngTopCell = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
Set rngBottomCell = ActiveCell.Offset(ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 0)
Set rngProductColumn = Range(rngTopCell, rngBottomCell)
```

And then get the blanks in that range:

```
Set rngProductBlanks = rngProductColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
```

This approach avoids a dependency on a particular column.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and select a cell unless you know the cell has been found.
This code will search row 1 for your header and then select the data below it (change `Rows(1)` to `Cells` to search the entire sheet).

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyData As Range

    'Ask the function to return the column headed "product"
    Set MyData = Return_Data("product")

    If MyData Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Column is empty."
    Else
        MsgBox MyData.Address
        MyData.Select
    End If

End Sub

Public Function Return_Data(Heading As String) As Range

    Dim rCol As Range
    'Dim rDataRange As Range
    Dim rLastCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PB")
        'Look for the column header.
        Set rCol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PB").Cells.Find( _
            What:=Heading, After:=.Cells.Cells(1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not rCol Is Nothing Then

            'Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rCol.Column).End(xlUp) 'Find last row in "product" column.
            Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp) 'Find last row in column 6 (F).

            If rLastCell.Row >= 2 Then
                'If the last cell is below the header than the column had data.
                'Set reference to one cell below the header down to the last cell.

                'Set Return_Data = .Range(rCol.Offset(1), rLastCell) 'If using last row in "product" column.
                Set Return_Data = .Range(rCol.Offset(1), .Cells(rLastCell.Row, rCol.Column)) 'If using last row in column 6.
            Else
                'Otherwise it's an empty column.
                Set Return_Data = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

I've added code to either find last row in "Product" column, or use "Dept" column for the last row.

Answer (score 0):

## Copy Range feat. some 'Parenting'

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColumnWithBlanks()

  Const cVntWsName As Variant = "PB"      ' Worksheet Name or Index ("PB" or 1)
  Const cLngHeaderRow As String = 1       ' Header Row
  Const cStrLast As String = "Dept"       ' Last Row Column Header
  Const cStrSource As String = "Product"  ' Source Column Header

  Dim rngLast As Range                    ' Last Row Column (Range)
  Dim rngSource As Range                  ' Source Column, Source Range

  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cVntWsName)

    ' Find first (header) cell in Last Row Column
    Set rngLast = .Rows(cLngHeaderRow).Find(What:=cStrLast, _
        After:=.Cells(cLngHeaderRow, Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    ' Find first (header) cell in Source Column
    Set rngSource = .Rows(cLngHeaderRow).Find(What:=cStrSource, _
        After:=.Cells(.Rows(cLngHeaderRow), Columns.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    ' Find last non-empty cell in Last Row Column
    Set rngLast = rngLast.Resize(Rows.Count - rngLast.Row + 1, 1) _
        .Find(What:="*", After:=rngLast.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) _
        .Offset(0, rngSource.Column - rngLast.Column)

    ' Calculate Source Range
    Set rngSource = .Range(rngSource.Offset(1, 0), rngLast)

    Set rngLast = Nothing

  End With

  Debug.Print rngSource.Address

  ' To refer to this worksheet you can use "rngSource.Parent" e.g.:
  Debug.Print rngSource.Parent.Name

  ' To refer to this workbook you can use "rngSource.Parent.Parent" e.g.:
  Debug.Print rngSource.Parent.Parent.Name

  ' To refer to another worksheet in this workbook you can use e.g.
  ' "rngSource.Parent.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet2")"
  Debug.Print rngSource.Parent.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet2").Name

  ' To copy the range to another range in this worksheet e.g.:
'  rngSource.Copy rngSource.Parent.Range("A1")

  Set rngSource = Nothing

End Sub
```